# Finite abelian group of order $a*b$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group with $|G|=ab$ so that $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Define $G(x)=\{g \in G\mid g^x=1\}$.

Prove that $G=G(a) \times G(b)$.

I think I have to use the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups but not sure how to apply it. Any hints?

Comment: Or you could use a Bezout relation $ua+vb=1$ to produce an isomorphism $G\to G(a)\times G(b)$ by sending $g$ to the pair $(g^{vb},g^{ua})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You can use the fundamental theorem on finite abelian group. Write $G=\mathbb{Z}_{n_1}\oplus\dots\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{n_r}$ with $n_i$ powers of primes. Then for each $n_i$ we have that $n_i\mid a$ or $n_i\mid b$ (Why?), and this or is exclusive. Meaning that both cannot happen (use the hypothesis of the problem). This should tell you how to break up your group.